# Magento 2.4.3p1 Translate "Show Password" text on Registration page

Tags: translate, magento2.4.3.p1

Magento 2.4.3 introduces a show password feature :

[image]

How can I translate the "Show Password" text?

An entry in the `i18n\XX_XX.csv` file does not work.

Comment: Have you enclosed it with __('') ?? or maybe has white space on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do following things.

1. Override this magento code file.

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/template/show-password.html

2. Then replace the following code

   ```
   <span translate="'Show Password'"></span>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <span data-bind="i18n: 'Show Password'"></span>
   ```
3. Now make the entry into proper translation file.
4. Run the magento command like upgrade, deply and then check.

Comment: Thanks for that, if you do a quick search on Google DE for "Customer Login" "Show Password" you will find all the stores that have upgraded to 2.4.3 but haven't fixed this bug yet! Perhaps this answer will help them...